# How can I track the sequence of <Import>s in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild

I have a complex set of MSBuild .targets files tha I am trying to debug. I want to figure out who is  who, in what order, when.

I tried using 'msbuild /v:diag' but I don't see this much detail in there.

Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

[MSBuild Sidekick](http://www.attrice.info/msbuild/) from Attrice Corp provides debugging functionality (single stepping and looking at variables) as well as an "Execution plan" view of your script hierarchy.